# Not using pre-compiled headers, but getting "PDB is not the same as when this precompiled header was built" errors"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008, I have a project in which I have "Not using pre-compiled headers" selected.  But when I try to build the project, I get errors complaining that "vc90.pdb is not the file that was used when this precompiled header was created" and a similar error for vc90.idb.  Why do I get these errors when I'm not using precompiled headers?

When I look in the intermediate directory, I see those two files.  If I delete them and then rebuild the project, the two files are immediately created, and then I get those errors.

Sometimes I can select "Create pre-compiled header" and it will build, and then I set it back to "Not using pre-compiled headers" and it will build again, but when I rebuild the entire solution the errors come back.  I've also tried deleting the project configuration and rebuilding it based on a configuration that doesn't have those errors, but the errors eventually return.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I fixed the problem by removing stdafx.cpp from my project.  I've no idea why that would have caused the problem in the first place, or why removing that file fixed the problem, or if the problem is truly, permanently fixed or not.

Comment: /Yc caused this problem.